# Breeze.Server.WebApi2 Unable to locate Dependency WebActivator

Tags: entity-framework-6, nuget, breeze, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package-restore

When I try to add the package 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2' thru my package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.0",
    "Breeze.Server.WebApi2": "1.5.4"
  },
```

I get the error:

```
Restoring packages for D:\VSProjects\(...)\project.json
Unable to locate Dependency WebActivator
Writing lock file D:\VSProjects\(...)\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 354ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\VSProjects\(...)\project.json
Unable to locate Dependency WebActivator
Writing lock file D:\VSProjects\(...)\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 562ms elapsed
```

The nuget page of 'WebActivator' says it is deprecated...
I've already tried installing the package 'WebActivatorEx' but that didn't help.

How can I get the package installed? Is there another version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the latest version, 1.5.5, just released yesterday.  The dependency is changed to WebActivatorEx.